# Не работает apache2 на порту

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Пытаюсь поставить html на порт. Веб сервер работает `apache2`. В основном файле пишу такой код

```
<VirtualHost *:6789>

    #DocumentRoot /var/www/
    WSGIDaemonProcess tjk.com.tm python-path=/home/gala/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/home/gala/gala
    WSGIProcessGroup tjk.com.tm

   <Directory /home/gala/gala/gala/>
      <Files wsgi.py>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
      </Files>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

перезагружаю `apache2`но на запрос на порт никакого ответа. Проверял `ufw` но его на сервере вовсе нет.

```
-bash: ufw: command not found
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указать апачу слушать этот порт

```
Listen 6789
<VirtualHost *:6789>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Потом перезапустить апач `service apache2 restart`

Но лучше эту настройку вынести в файл `ports.conf`

Вот пример дефолтной конфигурации этого файла

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 6789

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Он теперь слушает этот порт но при запросе переадресует на дефолтный 80 порт

Comment: Можете дать все файлы конфига

Comment: извините ваш метод работает. Ваш ответ верный. Я изменил вопрос. Если расскоментить DocumentRoot то остольное закомментить то работает на ура. Если же делать как в вопросе то переадресует на 80. Изза чего может быть данное поведение.